# I'm using concatenate function in excel but result is "true" and "false", why?

Tags: excel, function, formula

I'm trying to convert date and time to text but when I use this formula

`=concatenate(text(A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&" "&text(B2,"hh:mm:ss"))`

the result is "true" and "false"
[image]

I tried to look my old file, and the result should look like this
[image]

Comment: just use `&`, no need to use `concatenate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you even doing this?
In Excel, dates are stored as integers, while times are stored as decimals. As both are numbers, you can get a datetime (date AND time) by simply adding both values.

So, this formula should give you what you need:

```
=TEXT(A2+B2,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, i guess this also work for me
just wondering how a concatenate formular returning a result with "true" and "false"